# parent method to append vector to attribute of derived class

Tags: oop, python-2.7, numpy

My goal is to create a method, called `anotherVar`, in a class `Delta`, that adds an array to an existing array which I can call from a derived class (in this case `MyClass1`).

The code I have written here doesn't accomplish this. Where am I going wrong? Presumably it's my definition of `anotherVar`?

```
import numpy as np

class Delta(object):
    def anotherVar(self):
        return np.vstack(self)

class myClass1(Delta):
    def __init__(self, *myVars):
        self.__myArray = np.vstack(myVars)
    @property
    def myArray(self):
        return self.__myArray

someVars1 = [1,2,3]
someVars2 = [4,5,6]
someVars3 = [7,8,9]
myResult = myClass1(someVars1,someVars2,someVars2)
myResult.anotherVar = someVars3
print myResult.myArray

[[1 2 3]
[4 5 6]
[4 5 6]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 issues with your original code:

1. You're *rebinding* the identifier `anotherVar` of `Delta` to a variable. Most likely, you wanted to call

   ```
   myResult.anotherVar(someVars3)
   ```

   rather than

   ```
   myResult.anotherVar = someVars3
   ```

   as the latter *rebinds* the method `anotherVar` to the variable `someVars3`.
2. When you are using double underscores, you're using name mangling. If it's merely to make an attribute/method "[private](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references)", you shouldn't. Any developer who sees a single underscore in front of an attribute, will understand that it is liable to change and thus should not be depended on in the public API.

After changing 2 lines in `Delta` and changing double underscores into single underscores, your code works as you expect:

```
import numpy as np

class Delta(object):
    def anotherVar(self, arr):
        self._myArray = np.vstack((self._myArray, arr))

class myClass1(Delta):
    def __init__(self, *myVars):
        self._myArray = np.vstack(myVars)
    @property
    def myArray(self):
        return self._myArray
```

Comment: Of course. I see the call/rebinding issue you highlight. Thanks.